# How to get the difference between first row and current row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 columns in dataframe (date & sell_price). My expected output is like this. I want to add one more column named profit in dataframe that needs to be calculated by  current sell_price - first sell price (stars one)

```
        date            sell_price  profit(needs to be added)
    0   2018-10-26       **21.20**    NaN
    1   2018-10-29       15.15      -6.05
    2   2018-10-30       15.65      -5.55
    3   2018-10-31        0.15     -21.05
    4   2018-11-01        5.20     -16.00
```

I know the diff in pandas that gives difference between consecutive rows. How can we achieve expected o/p with diff or any other function on pandas?

Comment: Maybe something like `(df.loc[1:, "sell_price"] - df.loc[0, "sell_price"]).reindex(df.index, fill_value=np.nan)`?

Comment: It will be better to show first only sample input and then expected output @Devesh Agrawal to avoid confusions in IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For general `Index` like `DatetimeIndex` use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html), but it working only with positions, so necessary [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
pos = df.columns.get_loc('sell_price')
df['profit'] =  df.iloc[1:, pos] - df.iat[0, pos]
```

If default `RangeIndex` use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
df['profit'] =  df.loc[1:, 'sell_price'] - df.at[0, 'sell_price']
```

---

```
print (df)
         date  sell_price  profit
0  2018-10-26       21.20     NaN
1  2018-10-29       15.15   -6.05
2  2018-10-30       15.65   -5.55
3  2018-10-31        0.15  -21.05
4  2018-11-01        5.20  -16.00
```